# Access an NSUserDefault from multiple views

Tags: ios, xcode, view, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to access an NSUserDefault called prefs from multiple views. I am allocating prefs in one view but I don't know how to access it without just reallocating a new NSUserDefault in the second view.

Also, my operating system is ios.

Here is my FlipSideViewController Function:

The function in my FlipSideViewController: 'NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

```
- (IBAction) changeRate:(id)sender {

if (rate.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
    [prefs setInteger:1 forKey:@"myRate"];//save

}
else if (rate.selectedSegmentIndex == 2){
    [prefs setInteger:2 forKey:@"myRate"];//save
}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
};
```

And this is the MainViewController function:

```
 NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
// [prefs setValue: @"0" forKey: @"myRate"];

if (!([prefs valueForKey: @"myRate"])){
    [prefs setInteger:0 forKey: @"myRate"];
}

[prefs setInteger:2 forKey: @"myRate"];

int rateOption = [[prefs valueForKey: @"myRate"] intValue];

if (rateOption == 1)
{
    dayOrHourly.text = @"% of Day:";
    percentOrHours.hidden = YES;
    hours.hidden = YES;
    dayPercentage.hidden = NO;
}
else if (rateOption == 2)
{
    dayOrHourly.text = @"# of Hours:";
    percentOrHours.hidden = NO;
    dayPercentage.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with doing it separately in each VC?

Comment: Well, basically it's to save universal settings. If I allocate it a second time it creates a new instance of it do even though one view is saving data, the other view is reading null NSUserDefaults and so it cannot act on what the other page had set

Comment: Read my answer: use -(BOOL)synchronize.

Comment: can you give us details of `UISegmentedControl` you're using.

Comment: It's just a typical default UISegmentedControl. And I don't see the point of why you would need that. The problem isn't that it's not receiving input. I have tested that and it's working perfectly well and using the NSUserDefaults to save info for the flipSideView and can read it from the NSUserDefaults from the flipSideView and also the same with the mainView. The problem is simply just they won't share the NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 4):

Having more than one prefs for different views shouldn't be a problem. Just call

```
[prefObject synchronize];
```

when you modify one of the instances of NSUserDefaults in one view or try to access them from another view and you'll be fine.

But if you really want to keep a single object shared across all your view controllers, put it in your App Delegate.  [I must say, I don't see the point...]

Comment: That didn't work. If i try to just access them I get an error, and if I try to allocate it twice I get an "initializer element is not a compile time constant" error.

Answer (score 3):

`NSUserDefaults`  is a singleton class. You're not allocating instances of it, you're accessing it.

That said, have you tried using `objectForKey` instead of `valueForKey`? Values can't return values, (`... valueForKey] intValue];`) whereas objects do indeed return values.

Additionally, here's how I'd do it.

First, I'd define a constant in a global header, like so:

```
#define kSettings [NSUserDefaults standardUSerDefaults];
```

Then, you should be just fine accessing `NSUserDefaults` across views:

```
[kSettings setObject:@"This is a test." forKey:@"TestString"];
```

to read out the string, you would do this:

```
[kSettings objectForKey:@"TestString"];
```

I suggest defining some "global constants" for accessing objects stored in NSUserDefaults. For example:

```
#define kTestString [kSettings objectForKey:@"TestString"];
```